# jquery: shake div horizontally if input empty on submit?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use jquery to validate my form, if the user leaves either input box blank it will display a red border. Now I am trying to add a horizontal shake effect to the outer div 'home_column'.

However this is not working, the red borders around the input boxes are still displayed but there is no shake effect. please can someone show me where I am going wrong, thanks in advance

html

```
<div class="home_column">
<div class="login_form">
<form name="login" id="login" action="include/validate_login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 
<h21>Username</h21><br/>
<input type="text" class="login_form_front" id="myusername" name="myusername"><br/>
<h21>Password</h21><br/>
<input type="password" class="login_form_front" autocomplete="off"  id="mypassword" name="mypassword">
<br/>
<input type="submit" class="buttons_login" value="Login" id="login" name="login">
</form> 
</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
     var a = document.forms["login"]["myusername"].value;
     var b = document.forms["login"]["mypassword"].value;
     if (a == null || a == "" || b == null || b == "") {
     if (a == null || a == "") { document.forms["login"]["myusername"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
     if (b == null || b == "") { document.forms["login"]["mypassword"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}

     $( ".home_column" ).effect( "shake" );

    return false;   

     }
 }

 </script>
```

Comment: I would try to look for a similar solution on codepen or something. Maybe this one can help?http://codepen.io/insite-tyler/pen/rmiFf or to shake the entire form:  http://codepen.io/mattlibera/pen/dPdVOM

Comment: Did you already add jquery ui library as the effect api won't called unless you load it. And shake effect should already in horizontal state.

Comment: I think you're using jqueryUI effect('shake'), Is it not working? http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/

Comment: I think you missed JQuery-ui in ur imports. Add that after JQuery, it ll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not import yet, place this in your html head below after jquery core script src. Hope this help.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

On submit event when the field is empty you could assign a `shake` class to the `input` that runs a simple CSS3 animation — no need to load a whole fx library and increase the size of a page just for a single effect

e.g. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYRyBP

```
input.shake {
   -webkit-animation: shake .2s linear 0s 4;
   animation: shake .2s linear 0s 4;
}


@-webkit-keyframes shake {
   0% { transform: translateX(-5px); }
   50% { transform: translateX(5px); }
}
@keyframes shake {
   0% { transform: translateX(-5px); }
   50% { transform: translateX(5px); }
}
```